# Gráficos plotados de forma separada em única janela

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou tentando reproduzir o gráfico "1" abaixo para o modelo "2", porem não estou tendo sucesso em meu comando utilizado.

A ideia é separar em plots diferentes para uma melhor visualização (`geom_line + geom_point` parte superior e `geom_col` parte inferior).

Segue o comando  e figuras exemplificando os modelos.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
dt <- data.frame(periodo = c ("junho", "julho", "agosto"), peso = c(1, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3),  
                 atr = c(0.95, 0.5, 0.7, 0.75, 0.6, 0.8))
dt$grupo <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = nrow(dt)/2)
dt$periodo <- factor(dt$periodo, levels = c("junho", "julho", "agosto"))
dtF <- rbind(
       data.frame(when=dt$periodo, num=dt$peso, what="Peso"),
       data.frame(when=periodo, num=dt$atr, what="ATR"))
secondFacet <- FALSE +
ggplot(data = dtF, mapping = aes(peso, atr, fill = grupo))+
geom_col(position = "dodge")
facet_grid(what~., scale = "free") +
geom_bar(data=dtF[dtF$what=="Peso",], stat = "identity", fill = "grey") +
geom_line(data=dtF[dtF$what=="ATR",], size = 2, color = "blue") + 
scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, labels = function(b) {
if(!secondFacet) {secondFacet <<- TRUE 
  return(paste0(round(b * 100, 0), "%"))}else{return(b)}}) +
scale_x_date(name = "Day", labels = NULL)
```

[image: Figura exemplo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando a [resposta de Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/519100/117168) (e aproveitando os mesmos dados) com mais uma opção: o [pacote ggpubr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggpubr). É menos flexível do que gridExtra, mas para múltiplos gráficos tem opção de alinhar as áreas de plotagem e compartilhar legendas:

```
library(ggpubr)

ggarrange(g_col + labs(x = NULL), g_point,
  ncol = 1, align = "v", common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Carlos nesse caso o símbolo do gráfico de pontos e linhas também podem ser inclusos nessa legenda única ?

Comment: Não. A opção `common.legend` assume que ambas são iguais e  o `ggarrange` extrai e usa a do primeiro gráfico. Há maneiras de se fazer isso, mas não de maneira simples com o ggpubr. Como comentei na resposta, ele é amigável mas pouco flexível.

Answer (score 3):

Há mais de uma forma de fazer isso. A minha preferida é utilizando a função `grid.arrange` do pacote `gridExtra`. Para isto, basta criar dois os gráficos independentemente e salvá-los dentro de objetos no `R`.

Neste caso, criei o gráfico de colunas e salvei-o em um objeto chamado `g_col`, enquanto o gráfico de pontos e linhas foi salvo no objeto `g_point`.

Depois bastou juntá-los com a função `grid.arrange`, dizendo que eu gostaria de organizá-los em duas linhas de gráficos. Eu poderia ter colocado os gráficos em colunas, como no exemplo seguinte, mas a visualização não fica tão boa neste caso.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(gridExtra)

dt <- data.frame(periodo = c ("junho", "julho", "agosto"), 
                                 peso = c(1, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3),  
                                 atr = c(0.95, 0.5, 0.7, 0.75, 0.6, 0.8))
dt$grupo <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = nrow(dt)/2)
dt$periodo <- factor(dt$periodo, levels = c("junho", "julho", "agosto"))

g_col <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = peso, fill = grupo)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge")

g_point <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = atr, colour = grupo, group = grupo)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()

grid.arrange(g_point, g_col, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

```r
grid.arrange(g_point, g_col, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>