# Modificando rótulo de dados do gráfico

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Gostaria de deixar o rótulo de dados das barras do gráfico "1" igual ao gráfico 2, retirando a cor de fundo do rótulo e colorindo os números.

Estou utilizando o argumento `geom_label` em ambos os gráficos, porém não estou conseguindo a modificação.

Segue abaixo o comando e uma figura ilustrativa do gráfico.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggpubr)
dt <- data.frame(periodo = c ("Maio", "Junho"), 
             peso = c(14.1, 14.51, 12.25, 12.81),  
             atr = c(140.61, 130.29, 131.5, 146.23))
dt$LOCAL <- rep(c("1", "5"), each = nrow(dt)/2)
dt$periodo <- factor(dt$periodo, levels = c("Maio", "Junho"))

g_col <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = peso, fill = LOCAL, label = rownames(dt))) +
geom_col(position = "dodge")+
theme_gray() +
geom_label(aes(label = peso), position = position_dodge(width = 1), fontface = "bold",vjust = 
-0.1,show.legend = FALSE)+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,25))+
labs(x = "Período", y = "", title = "", subtitle = "Evolução peso")+
theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_text(face = "bold", size = 10, colour = "black"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"))+
scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) 

g_point <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = atr, colour = Talhão, shape = Talhão)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line() +
geom_label(aes(label = atr), position = position_nudge(y = 1.1),fontface = "bold")+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(130,150))+
scale_shape_manual("Talhão", values = c(18, 19))+
geom_point(fill = "black", size = 3, stroke = 2)+
labs(x = "", y = "ATR", title = "", subtitle = "Evolução ATR")+
theme_gray()+
theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_text(face = "bold", size = 10, color = "black"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"))+
scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
ggarrange(g_col + labs(x = "Período"), g_point + labs(x = "Período"),
      ncol = 2, align = "v", common.legend = TRUE, legend = "right")
```

[image: figura ilustrativa]

Comment: Patrick, seja benvindo ao StackOverflow Português! O ideal é que o código seja reproduzível. Os dados de Talhão estão ausentes no código.

Comment: Daniel boa observação !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1.

Primeiro carregar os pacotes necessários, sem o pacote `lubridate` que não é utilizado no código abaixo.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggpubr)
```

E simplificar ambos os gráficos criando um `theme` próprio, comum a todos os gráficos abaixo.

```
theme_patrick <- function(){ 
  theme_gray() %+replace%    #replace elements we want to change
    theme(
      axis.title.y=element_blank(),
      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_text(face = "bold", size = 10, color = "black"),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold")
  )
}
```

### 2.

O primeiro gráfico tem o `atr` tanto no gráfico de barras como no gráfico da direita. Assim os rótulos condizem com os valores das barras.

```
g_col <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = atr)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = LOCAL), position = "dodge") +
  geom_label(aes(label = atr, colour = LOCAL),
             fill = NA,
             position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
             fontface = "bold", vjust = -0.1, 
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Período", y = "", title = "", subtitle = "Evolução peso")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 250))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  theme_patrick()

g_point <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = atr, colour = LOCAL, shape = LOCAL)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, stroke = 2) +
  geom_label(aes(label = atr), position = position_nudge(y = 1.1), fontface = "bold") +
  labs(x = "", y = "ATR", title = "", subtitle = "Evolução ATR")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(130, 150))+
  scale_shape_manual("Talhão", values = c(18, 19))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  theme_patrick()

ggarrange(g_col + labs(x = "Período"), g_point + labs(x = "Período"),
          ncol = 2, align = "v", 
          common.legend = TRUE, legend = "right")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 3.

Agora um gráfico de barras com os valores dos pesos e os rótulos com valores do `atr`, tal como pedido. Não creio que faça sentido, basta ver que no grupo de barras da direita os valores crescem mas as barras decrescem. O segundo gráfico não é alterado.

```
g_col2 <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = peso)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = LOCAL), position = "dodge") +
  geom_label(aes(label = atr, colour = LOCAL),
             fill = NA,
             position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
             fontface = "bold", vjust = -0.1, 
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Período", y = "", title = "", subtitle = "Evolução peso")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 25))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  theme_patrick()

ggarrange(g_col2 + labs(x = "Período"), g_point + labs(x = "Período"),
          ncol = 2, align = "v", 
          common.legend = TRUE, legend = "right")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Rui, excelente explicação. Existe a possibilidade da criação de um rótulo que evidência a diferença entre as barras ou dos pontos? Não encontrei pesquisas sobre.

Comment: @patrickcesar Talvez um dos gráficos das suas [perguntas anteriores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/519097/gr%c3%a1ficos-plotados-de-forma-separada-em-%c3%banica-janela). Ou quer mesmo diferenças (`peso - atr`)?

Comment: No caso seria no gráfico de colunas. A ideia é tentar mostrar a diferença entre as colunas de cada mês, coluna maior em relação a menor e essa diferença ser evidenciada em algum ponto do gráfico.. As vezes em um rótulo logo acima ou dentro das barras. A ideia é tentar mostrar todas essas informações em um único gráfico, não sei se possui um modelo mais apropriado..

Comment: @patrickcesar Acho que só vendo o que quer, não pode dar um exemplo?