# Como fazer camadas no ggplot2 com dois gráficos de grandezas diferentes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou começando com programação e estou tentando plotar um gráfico sobrepondo dados extraídos de dois dataframes.

O código é o seguinte:

```
#Real Gross Domestic Product - GDP
USgdp <- read_csv('GDP.csv')
colnames(USgdp) <- c("Date","GDP")

#ISM PMI Composite Index
USpmi <- Quandl('ISM/MAN_PMI')

#GDP
gGDP <- ggplot(data = USgdp,
        aes(x = Date, y = GDP,
           colour = GDP)) +
        labs(title = "U.S. Real Gross Domestic Product", x = "Date", y = "GDP") +
        theme_minimal() +
        guides(fill = "none", colour = "none") +
  geom_bar(stat = 'Identity')
```

[image: Resultado do gráfico de barras]

```
#ISM PMI
gPMI <- ggplot(data = USpmi,
        aes(x = Date, y = PMI,
           colour = "darkred")) +
        guides(fill = "none", colour = "none") +
    geom_line(size = 1)
```

[image: O resultado do segundo gráfico é o seguinte:]

O zero para a leitura do gráfico de linha corresponde ao valor 50 do eixo y.

Como eu posso sobrepor estes dois gráficos alinhando seus respectivos zeros como nesse exemplo?

[image: Gráfico de exemplo]

Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Para ter sua pergunta respondida adequadamente, forneça um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Se sua dúvida não depende dos seus dados, use um conjunto embutido no R, ou gere dados de exemplo (incluindo o código na pergunta). Confira [esta postagem sobre como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) para mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

Modifique os valores da variável a ser sobreposta (PMI - 50, no caso). Para garantir uma interpretação melhor dos dados, adicione um eixo secundário correspondente e indique para `sec_axis` a transformação contrária:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(7269)
dadosGDP <- data.frame(ano = 1950:2020, GDP = sample(-20:20, 71, TRUE))
dadosPMI <- data.frame(ano = 1950:2020, PMI = sample(30:80, 71, TRUE))

ggplot(dadosGDP, aes(ano, GDP)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = GDP)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = PMI-50, color = "PMI"), dadosPMI) +  # aes(..., color = "PMI") e scale_color_manual para exibir melhor na legenda
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.+50, "PMI"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas fique ciente de que sobrepor dois gráficos com escalas de grandeza diferente é uma prática ruim de visualização de dados, motivo pelo qual o ggplot2 não possui uma forma automática de fazer isso. Considere compor um gráfico com os plots separados: [Gráficos plotados de forma separada em única janela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/519097/117168)

Comment: Ajudou muito, obrigado. Consegui plotar como no seus exemplo, a única coisa que ainda não consegui ajustar foram os lables do eixo secundário em y que está com a ordem invertida. Estou procurando, mas só acho como fazer o flip dos eixos

Comment: Desculpe, eu tinha digitado errado a transformação, já atualizei a resposta. Se considerou a resposta útil, [não precisa agradecer, apenas use o sistema de votação do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). E mesmo que a sua dúvida tenha sido solucionada, sugiro editar sua pergunta para conter um [exemplo reproduzível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); isso auxilia outras pessoas que consultarem o site ou que quiserem propor outras soluções.